# Get data from second dataframe based on first dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two PySpark Dataframes `df1` and `df2` with following schemas

```
df1:

root
 |-- RCBNorthAmps: double (nullable = true)
 |-- RCBSouthAmps: double (nullable = true)
 |-- RCBTOB: double (nullable = true)
 |-- time: timestamp (nullable = true)

+-----------------+-----------------+------+-------------------+
|     RCBNorthAmps|     RCBSouthAmps|RCBTOB|               time|
+-----------------+-----------------+------+-------------------+
|             88.6|             89.6| 234.0|2019-01-01 00:00:00|
|          88.6699|            89.77| 234.4|2019-01-01 00:00:01|
|            88.74|            89.94| 234.8|2019-01-01 00:00:02|
|            88.81|            90.11| 235.2|2019-01-01 00:00:03|
|            88.88|            90.28| 235.6|2019-01-01 00:00:04|
showing first 5 rows
```

```
df2:

root
 |-- slip_start: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- slip_end: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- premature: integer (nullable = true)

+-------------------+-------------------+---------+
|         slip_start|           slip_end|premature|
+-------------------+-------------------+---------+
|2019-01-01 00:06:50|2019-01-01 00:06:50|        0|
|2019-01-01 00:10:30|2019-01-01 00:10:30|        0|
|2019-01-01 00:10:40|2019-01-01 00:10:40|        0|
|2019-01-01 00:10:50|2019-01-01 00:10:50|        0|
|2019-01-01 00:15:10|2019-01-01 00:15:10|        0|
showing first 5 rows
```

Is it possible to create a new column in df2 and fill its values by considering the following aggregations?

```
variance = df1.filter(df1.time > df2_perticular_row.slip_start)['RCBNorthAmps'].var()
return variance # variance in df1 for the particular row in df2
```

For each row in df2, there has to be some aggregation in df1. And then get it back in the new column and get the final output in df2 like this

```
+-------------------+-------------------+---------+
|         slip_start|           slip_end|premature| variance
+-------------------+-------------------+---------+
|2019-01-01 00:06:50|2019-01-01 00:06:50|        0|    0.0123         
|2019-01-01 00:10:30|2019-01-01 00:10:30|        0|     0.323         
|2019-01-01 00:10:40|2019-01-01 00:10:40|        0|     0.013         
|2019-01-01 00:10:50|2019-01-01 00:10:50|        0|    0.0123         
|2019-01-01 00:15:10|2019-01-01 00:15:10|        0|    0.1423
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the two dataframes using `df2["slip_start"] < df1["time"]` as join condition and then group the result by the column `slip_start`. The aggregation function would be [var_samp](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.var_samp.html).

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2.join(df1, df2["slip_start"] < df1["time"], "left_outer") \
      .groupBy("slip_start") \
      .agg(F.var_samp("RCBNorthAmps")) \
      .show()
```